# How can I test my Dao method with Mockito If I get connection by method parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, database-connection, dao

I have a DAO class whose methods use connection recieved by given parameters

example

```
@Override
    public boolean insertCarCategory(Connection connection, CarCategory carCategory) throws MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException, SQLException {
        int rowNum = 0;
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try{
            String query = QueriesUtil.getQuery("insertCarCategory");
            con = connection;
            statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, carCategory.getCarCategory());
            statement.setDouble(2, carCategory.getCostPerOneKilometer());
            statement.setDouble(3, carCategory.getDiscount());
            statement.setBytes(4, ImageUtil.imageToByte(carCategory.getCarCategoryImage()));
            rowNum = statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            throw new MySQLEXContainer.MySQLDBExecutionException("Bad execution",e);
        }finally {
            ConnectionUtil.oneMethodToCloseThemAll(null,statement,null);
        }
        return rowNum > 0;
    }
```

I have service class that use factory to obtain connection and pass it to Dao method and I tested Service class.But How can I test Dao class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test using mocked objects, look for Mockito library (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_overview.htm)

Sample test case

Java Classes and Test class with test cases

```
public class CarCategory {
    private String carCategory;
    private Double costPerOneKilometer;
    private Double discount;
    private byte[] carCategoryImage;

    public CarCategory(String carCategory, Double costPerOneKilometer, Double discount, byte[] carCategoryImage) {
        this.carCategory = carCategory;
        this.costPerOneKilometer = costPerOneKilometer;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.carCategoryImage = carCategoryImage;
    }

    public String getCarCategory() {
        return carCategory;
    }

    public void setCarCategory(String carCategory) {
        this.carCategory = carCategory;
    }

    public Double getCostPerOneKilometer() {
        return costPerOneKilometer;
    }

    public void setCostPerOneKilometer(Double costPerOneKilometer) {
        this.costPerOneKilometer = costPerOneKilometer;
    }

    public Double getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(Double discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public byte[] getCarCategoryImage() {
        return carCategoryImage;
    }

    public void setCarCategoryImage(byte[] carCategoryImage) {
        this.carCategoryImage = carCategoryImage;
    }

}


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CarCategoryDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CarCategoryDao.class);

    public boolean insertCarCategory(Connection connection, CarCategory carCategory) throws SQLException {
        int rowNum = 0;
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try{
            String query = "insertCarCategory";
            con = connection;
            statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, carCategory.getCarCategory());
            statement.setDouble(2, carCategory.getCostPerOneKilometer());
            statement.setDouble(3, carCategory.getDiscount());
            statement.setBytes(4, carCategory.getCarCategoryImage());
            rowNum = statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("sas",e);
            throw e;
        }
        return rowNum > 0;
    }
}



import com.dao.utils.CarCategory;
import com.dao.utils.CarCategoryDao;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;


import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CarCategoryDaoTest {

    @Mock
    private Connection connection;

    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement statement;

    @InjectMocks
    private CarCategoryDao carCategoryDao;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws SQLException {
        int actualResponse = 0;
        CarCategory cc = new CarCategory("abc", 10.2, 11.1, new byte[100]);
        
            when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(statement);
            when(statement.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(actualResponse);
            boolean result = carCategoryDao.insertCarCategory(connection, cc);
            Assert.assertFalse(result);
        
    }

    @Test
    public void test2()  throws SQLException {
        int actualResponse = 2;
        CarCategory cc = new CarCategory("abc", 10.2, 11.1, new byte[100]);
        
            when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(statement);
            when(statement.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(actualResponse);
            boolean result = carCategoryDao.insertCarCategory(connection, cc);
            Assert.assertTrue(result);
        
    }

    @Test(expected = SQLException.class)
    public void test3()  throws SQLException {
        int actualResponse = 2;
        CarCategory cc = new CarCategory("abc", 10.2, 11.1, new byte[100]);
       
            when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(statement);
            when(statement.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(actualResponse);
            when(statement.executeUpdate()).thenThrow(SQLException.class);
            boolean result = carCategoryDao.insertCarCategory(connection, cc);
        
    }

}
```